# signal in C++: using a member function

Tags: c++, signals

I have this problem with `signal()`:

This code compiles fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void terminate( int param )
{
  printf ( "Terminating program...\n" );
  exit( 1 );
}

int main()
{
    signal( SIGTERM, terminate );
    return 0;
}
```

The following code, however, throws this error:

```
g++ -Wall -c -g goober.cpp
goober.cpp: In member function `void GOOBER::yarrgh()':
goober.cpp:5: error: argument of type `void (GOOBER::)(int)' does not match `
   void (*)(int)'
make: *** [goober.o] Error 1
```

### goober.h:

```
#ifndef GOOBER_H
#define GOOBER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

class GOOBER {
public:
    GOOBER(){}
    ~GOOBER(){}
    void yarrgh();
    void terminate( int param );
};

#endif
```

### goober.cpp:

```
#include "goober.h"

void GOOBER::yarrgh()
{
    signal( SIGTERM, terminate );
}

void GOOBER::terminate( int param )
{
    printf( "Terminating program...\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

### driver.cpp:

```
#include "goober.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GOOBER G;
    G.yarrgh();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't see any difference in the code, other than I'm calling `signal()` in a member.  Any ideas what's wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to declare your `terminate()` function as `static`:

```
class GOOBER {
    // ...
    static void terminate(int param);
};
```

This is because that as a non-static member function, the `terminate()` function expects to be passed the (hidden) `this` parameter to point to some instance of the object. Since the signal mechanism doesn't know about this (or about anything much of C++), you need to use a `static` function so that there is no hidden `this` parameter.

Comment: I would not trust a static member to have the correct linkage requirements for a C function.

Answer (score 7):

I can tell you what's wrong:

You cannot use a non-static member function like a normal function pointer.  Member functions always have an implicit `this` argument, which is provided (implicitly) by the caller.  A C API cannot do this.

Answer (score 5):

Terminate has to be a static function in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Member function have different signature from normal function that not belong any class. However, static member function have the same signature with normal function. So, you could declare your terminate member function in GOOBER class as static.